# View iTunes store in a browser

Tags: itunes, web-browser

I'd like to be able to get the same view into iTunes U in a web browser, instead of iTunes. Major reason - to be able to open multiple tabs, make bookmarks etc.

However when I open iTunes URL in a browser, it displays standard "One Moment Please.
Connecting to the iTunes Store." blurb (see for yourself [here](http://itunes.apple.com/au/institution/yale-university/id341649956))

Is there a way to circumvent this 'iTunes detection', which presumably those pages do?

Answer (score 2):

It would be great, IMO lack of tabs and bookmarking has always been a little bit of a failure for the iTunes store. 
Now, unfortunately, the iTunes store is difficult for browsers to interpret, because it was written in a wacky XML format instead of a browser standard HTML.

About three years ago it emerged that a coder had written an app that decodes this XML into HTML, and therefore could be viewed in the browser etc.

This is the link for it, but unfortunately, for me anyway, it seems to be dead.

Apple released 'iTunes Preview,' where you can browse content, as a web based store with links over the iTunes, but I don't think this is quite what you were looking for.

[iTunes Preview](http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/music/id34)

Someone else may have a solution, but sorry I can't help more!

([Source](http://www.labnol.org/software/browse-itunes-without-installing-software/6657/))